# iOS: UILabel How to achieve TextAlignment.justified on one line

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, text-alignment

How to achieve TextAlignment.justified on one line of a label.

1. I have one UILabel of fixed width (200)
2. Number of lines of this Label is always 1
3. I want the text of this **One Line** to be justified on both edges

So far What I have seen the TextAlignment.justified is only applied on paragraph and also on paragraph it is not applied on last line or single line.